# Failed to commit spark job out of CDH 6.2 servers

Tags: apache-spark

CDH 6.2 is deployed on 3 servers: `cm01`, `cm02`, `cm03`.

`spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf spark.yarn.archive=hdfs:///share/spark-libs.jar` works if I login with `rd` account and run command on any one of these servers.

Now I want to submit spark job from server `dev01` with user `rd`. I copied some directories from CDH to `dev01` and setup environment `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and `HADOOP_HOME`. However, yarn always complains:

```
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
19/07/30 14:03:38 ERROR cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: YARN application has exited unexpectedly with state FAILED! Check the YARN application logs for more details.
19/07/30 14:03:38 ERROR cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Diagnostics message: Uncaught exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:493)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:798)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:798)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to iZ8vb501or059rpllhr7i9Z:35937
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:250)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:192)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: iZ8vb501or059rpllhr7i9Z
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:146)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:143)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:143)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:43)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:63)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:55)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:57)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:32)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:108)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:208)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:49)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:188)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:174)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:481)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:82)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:978)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:512)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:423)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:482)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    ... 1 more

19/07/30 14:03:38 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
19/07/30 14:03:38 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spark context stopped while waiting for backend
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.waitBackendReady(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:818)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.postStartHook(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:106)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:43)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:45)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:49)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$quietRun$1.apply(IMain.scala:231)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$quietRun$1.apply(IMain.scala:231)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:221)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietRun(IMain.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:109)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:109)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$anonfun$$loopPostInit$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$anonfun$$loopPostInit$1$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$anonfun$$loopPostInit$1$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:199)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$mumly$1.apply(ILoop.scala:189)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:221)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.mumly(ILoop.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$anonfun$$loopPostInit$1(SparkILoop.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$startup$1$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$startup$1$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.withSuppressedSettings$1(SparkILoop.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.startup$1(SparkILoop.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:282)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runClosure(SparkILoop.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
19/07/30 14:03:38 ERROR repl.Main: Failed to initialize Spark session.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spark context stopped while waiting for backend
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.waitBackendReady(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:818)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.postStartHook(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:106)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:43)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:45)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:49)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$quietRun$1.apply(IMain.scala:231)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$quietRun$1.apply(IMain.scala:231)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:221)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietRun(IMain.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:109)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:109)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$anonfun$$loopPostInit$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$anonfun$$loopPostInit$1$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$anonfun$$loopPostInit$1$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:199)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$mumly$1.apply(ILoop.scala:189)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:221)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.mumly(ILoop.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$anonfun$$loopPostInit$1(SparkILoop.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$startup$1$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$startup$1$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.withSuppressedSettings$1(SparkILoop.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.startup$1(SparkILoop.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:282)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runClosure(SparkILoop.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

It seems RPC timeout exception. I have no clue to fix it. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `java.net.UnknownHostException: iZ8vb501or059rpllhr7i9Z` seems like a good clue.

Comment: Great. It is the hostname of `dev01`. I found the problem. Thank you very much.